# Como hago una peticion con mi token en un API? - JS?

Tags: javascript, api, rest

Este es mi código actual=

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const myHeader = new Headers({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer  eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJkM2NIVUVibVJoc1EzeXhNbzV2VnliSTFzaDZCSDJZRCIsImlhdCI6MTU4NTkzMjYzNDU0OH0.tMSht_M3ryQl5IqCirhYR1gb8j3FQ26vILT4Qpx4XrdFz-zUmqbgFYiKTaZHPpB85etRIMhxVoZf6tOrHy0fnA'
    });

const myInit = { 
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeader,
    mode: 'cors',     
    cache: 'default'  
};

const myrequest = new Request('https://eshop-deve.herokuapp.com/api/v2/orders/2117155815564',myInit);

fetch(myrequest)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {console.log(data);})
.catch(err=> console.log(`Hubo error ${err}`))
```

me aparece el error:

> Object { statusCode: 404, error: "Not Found" }

//Es mi token ---->

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJkM2NIVUVibVJoc1EzeXhNbzV2VnliSTFzaDZCSDJZRCIsImlhdCI6MTU4NTkzMjYzNDU0OH0.tMSht_M3ryQl5IqCirhYR1gb8j3FQ26vILT4Qpx4XrdFz-zUmqbgFYiKTaZHPpB85etRIMhxVoZf6tOrHy0fnA
```

Comment: La pagina de la API a la que deseas acceder no existe, estas seguro que esa es la URL correcta de la API?, o se habran equivocado al dartela?, no me refiero a la base URL si no al endpoint.

Comment: Tu código luce bien, el problema es que la página a la que apunta la solicitud devuelve un error 404. Como comenta @Riven, debes asegurarte que el endpoint de la API que tratas de consumir efectivamente está activo. Ponte en contacto con los encargados de dicha implementación. No hay nada más que podamos hacer aquí. Saludos